# Update Google Play Music ID3 tag

Tags: android, tags, refresh, id3v2

I'm making an Android Application which adds `id3v2` tag to `mp3` files. It is ok but when I open Google Play Music the `mp3` tags are not updated. Even if I clear the cache.

But when I open my mp3 file tagged into my application in Windows, all tags show the changes correctly.

How can I force Play Music to refresh tags programmatically or by tips I can insert in my application.

Thanks..

Comment: Does this occurs only with Google Play Music or with any other media players as well?

Comment: I test an other and it's the same thing no tags are updated i clear cache but no results. I made a new test, i download star Music editor and when I search a Music tagged by my application tags are not updated but when I open it, album Cover, artists and all tags are here, and when I save Google Play is updated.

Comment: Oh i find something there is a app in Android called media storage who store Music in it. I think i do update tag of my file and tag are stored into this media storage.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, i need to update the media library in android :

```
public void updateMediaScanner(String path){
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {}
    });
}
```